# How set view from another xml?

Tags: android, xml, view, set, setcontentview

I'm trying set the background of my ImageView, but the layout isn't the setContentView of the activity.

My layout pieza_j1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pieza1"
    android:src="@drawable/osin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

My Game Activity. I'm trying set the background, but doesn't work:

```
private void setIcon() {
    switch (p1) {
    case 0: 
        View pieza_1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pieza_j1, null);
        ImageView pieza1 = (ImageView) pieza_1.findViewById(R.id.pieza1);
        pieza1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arribin);
```

...

The layout of the Game activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        >

        <com.sistemasmas.line.views.TopView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id ="@+id/topview"
        />


         <com.sistemasmas.line.views.GameView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id ="@+id/gameview"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"

         />  

        <com.sistemasmas.line.views.BottomView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id ="@+id/bottomview"

        />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And a GameView:

```
private int getPieceId(){
    if(board.getPlayersGo()==Players.PLAYER1){


        return R.layout.pieza_j1;
    }
    else{

        return R.layout.pieza_j2;
    }
}

private void addPiece(int i){
    boolean p = powerBall.playNow();
    if(powerPressed){
        p = true;
    }
    MarginLayoutParams mp = new MarginLayoutParams(gameBoard.getPieceDiam(),gameBoard.getPieceDiam());
    if(p){
        newPiece = lInf.inflate(getPowerId(), null);
    }
    else{
        newPiece = lInf.inflate(getPieceId(), null);
    }
```

...

Comment: What should happen ? You infalte a layout set some resources and then ? You never attach this view to your layout .

Comment: I want set the background image of the ImageView, but doesn't work, the image doesn't change.

Comment: Where is your imageview added to the layout ?

Comment: In the GameView where says return R.layout.pieza_j1; and newPiece = lInf.inflate(getPieceId(), null);

Comment: I'm understand you right that u assume your infalte call will add the view to the layout ?

Comment: Ok, then you'll happy to hear that just inflating without a parent does not attach a view.Use inflate (getpowerId(),parent,true). Or attach it manually.Assuming your 'gameview' is a viewgroup.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good and I may not express well. The image appears, but when I decide to change the background of it, isn't work.